# Change the descriptor information of a mouse to look like another mouse

Tags: arduino, usb, mouse, hid

I don't know if this is the right platform to ask this question but here's what I want to achieve.

I have a protected laptop that only accepts a certain type of mouse to be connected. I want to make a normal mouse to appear as the allowed category mouse to be connected to that laptop. Is it possible in some way?

For example: I was able to change the descriptor information of an [ATTiny85 microcontroller with USB interface](https://funduinoshop.com/elektronische-module/sonstige/mikrocontroller/attiny85-mikrocontroller-mit-usb-schnittstelle) and make it look like a Logitech mouse. But to make it appear like a Logitech mouse I had to install the ATTiny board driver on my laptop. Installing any external driver on that protected laptop is not possible due to security reasons.

Now, I want to do the same thing with a normal mouse and make it appear as a Logitech mouse on my laptop.

Comment: `Installing any external driver on that protected laptop is not possible due to security reasons.` Is it allowed to manually add allowed drivers to other devices? or to edit .inf files ?

Comment: I didn't understand your question. There's nothing external resources we can add/install on the protected laptop. The laptop only allows the connection with a Logitech mouse, so, to me the only way is to change the descriptor information (VID and PID) of a simple mouse to make it look like a Logitech mouse.